# How to store user hobbies in a MySQL database, then retrieve a list of users with common hobbies using JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc, web-applications

I have a web application, where in the user registration form, the user will fill out a small survey (i.e. Y/N checkboxes) to choose their hobbies out of a preset list of 10-15 hobbies. I want to be able to store each user's chosen hobbies in a mySQL database, then retreive a list of users with 1 or more common hobbies. How might I implement this in JDBC and mySQL?

I've tried having 1 table containing user account information

```
| userID | username | password   |
| 1      | mark     |    fdaf    |
| 2      | sam      |     dfad   |
| 3      | josh     |   teyto    |
```

and 1 table containing only available hobbies

```
| interestID | interest  |
| 1          | Cars      |
| 2          | Computers |
| 3          | Swimming  |
```

And joining them in a many to many relationship.

```
| userID | interestID  |
|    1   |    1        |
|    1   |    2        |
|    2   |    3        |
|    3   |    1        |
|    3   |    3        |
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. How do I retreive a list of all users that have common interests with a specific user. Say input user 1 -> retrieve a list containing users 2 and 3; input user 2 -> retrieve a list containing user 1.

Comment: Step 1) Learn about [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Step 2) Try something. Step 3) If you have trouble, post a Stack Overflow question including what you've tried so we can help get that to the finish line. This question's way too premature to answer here, it'd take hours to explain the fundamentals. There's a multitude of training courses, online and otherwise, paid and free, that covers this.

Comment: I edited my post. Is this sufficient?